# Kryonet reliability

Tags: java, networking, kryonet

Is there anyone who has used the Java Kryonet library in a project willing to share their experience?  I've seen it recommended a few times, but haven't actually seen anybody talk about their experiences using it.

Specifically, I want to make sure that it is reliable and relatively stable. Or should I consider using something like Google protocol buffers with custom networking code?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725233/kryo-serialization-library-is-it-used-in-production)?

Comment: Nope, hadn't seen that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have discussed the kryonet and kryo in my master's thesis and compared it some of the contemporaries; that should give some information and analysis about Kryo: http://de.scribd.com/doc/67084961/MasterArbeit

Answer (score 0):

Answering the other half of your question that isn't addressed by the older one, Protocol Buffers have the advantage of being much more widely deployed, so you're less likely to run into major bugs.  There are serious downsides, though, not least the facts that (1) you have to define your format using an IDL and then use PB's generated classes (meaning you may have to copy data in and out of your own back-end objects, which might result in lower performance) and (2) PB doesn't support polymorphism except through a variety of difficult-to-manage hacks.

So, if you're just looking for a straightforward way of transferring structured (but not object-oriented) data from one endpoint to another, Protocol Buffers is probably your best bet.  More complex scenarios probably favour Kryonet.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I developed a game with kryonet and it works like a charm. It is also very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with Kryonet and making a game. I have myself found it as a very helpful and easy to use library. It has a very simple API which makes life very easy. I won't say it is as powerful as something like Netty or Apache Mina but it does all the required tasks. I personally love it and I will use it everywhere I can unless I require something more powerful or sending huge data as other libraries provide much more than KryoNet when it comes to sending data.