# Storing an object to a file

Tags: scala

I want to save an object (an instance of a class) to a file. I didn't find any valuable example of it. Do I need to use serialization for it?

How do I do that?

**UPDATE**:
Here is how I tried to do that

```
import scala.util.Marshal
import scala.io.Source
import scala.collection.immutable
import java.io._

object Example {
  class Foo(val message: String) extends scala.Serializable
  val foo = new Foo("qweqwe")                    
  val out = new FileOutputStream("out123.txt")
  out.write(Marshal.dump(foo))
  out.close
}
```

First of all, out123.txt contains many extra data and it was in a wrong encoding. My gut tells me there should be another proper way.

Comment: Yes. The procedure is called serialization.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple, hassle-free, zero-boilerplate serialization in Scala/Java similar to Python's Pickle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590557/simple-hassle-free-zero-boilerplate-serialization-in-scala-java-similar-to-pyt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible to serialize to and deserialize from JSON using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).
A nice wrapper that makes it Scala friendly is [Jacks](https://github.com/wg/jacks)

JSON has the following advantages

- a simple human readable text
- a rather efficient format byte wise
- it can be used directly by Javascript
- and even be natively stored and queried using a DB like [Mongo DB](http://www.mongodb.org/)

(Edit) **Example Usage**

Serializing to JSON:

```
val json = JacksMapper.writeValueAsString[MyClass](instance)
```

... and deserializing

```
val obj = JacksMapper.readValue[MyClass](json)
```

Comment: Does not work in Scala 12 :(  No release on MVN for 6+ years https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lambdaworks/jacks

Answer (score 6):

On the last ScalaDays Heather introduced a new library which gives a new cool mechanism for serialization - [pickling](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/pickling/). I think it's would be an idiomatic way in scala to use serialization and just what you want.

Check out a [paper](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/files/pickling.pdf) on this topic, [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/heathermiller/on-pickles-and-spores-improving-support-for-distributed-programming-in-scala) and [talk](http://parleys.com/play/51c3799fe4b0d38b54f4625a/chapter0/about) on ScalaDays'13

Comment: `println(List(42).pickle)` -- what makes it write to a file?

Comment: @MariusKavansky nothing, serialization is just for transforming your object graph into the binary form, but writting to some target (file, network) you should handle yourself. Make a typeclass for this with some method like writeTo("filePath")

Comment: I rather asking about writing to a file to be able to ready it later and it should be written so that a human can read easily.

Comment: besides, there is an error in sbt if I follow the instruction from their website, it doesn't find current picking version (SNAPSHOT).

Comment: You want to read in a file? Then that's not serialization, what's you need. Serialization is all about transforming your object into binary format

Comment: what's the name of it then? I have many fields (val) and nested classes in the main class I want to store in a file.

Comment: @MariusKavansky sorry, never heard of such thing

Comment: FWIW, it's possible to use scala/pickling to write to a file. We're working on a stable release + documentation at the moment, but interim instructions for writing JSON to file are [here](https://github.com/scala/pickling/issues/5). Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Twitter Chill to handle your serialization: https://github.com/twitter/chill. It's a Scala helper for the Kyro serialization library. The documentation/example on the Github page looks to be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: is there any simpler way to do that?

Comment: Try Java's ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream? I can't think of any reason they won't work for Scala just as well as they work for Java.

Answer (score 1):

*Just add my answer here for the convenience of someone like me.*

The [`pickling`](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/pickling/) library, which is mentioned by [@4lex1v](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17540472/1808436), only supports Scala 2.10/2.11 but I'm using Scala 2.12. So I'm not able to use it in my project.

And then I find out [`BooPickle`](https://github.com/suzaku-io/boopickle). It supports Scala 2.11 as well as 2.12!

Here's the example:

```
import boopickle.Default._

val data = Seq("Hello", "World!")
val buf = Pickle.intoBytes(data)
val helloWorld = Unpickle[Seq[String]].fromBytes(buf)
```

More details please check [here](https://boopickle.suzaku.io/).